# jprofiler on 64bit Linux: i386?

Tags: jprofiler

I am installing jprofiler on 64bit Scientific Linux release 6.2 (Carbon)

But the installer shows:

```
---> Package jprofiler.i386 0:8.0.4-1 will be installed
```

Should I be worried that the Arch is i386?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JProfiler ships with native libraries for 32-bit and 64-bit. They are located in `bin/linux-x86` and `bin/linux-x64`.

The JProfiler GUI is written in Java and uses the appropriate JRE. The selection of the correct native library is only important when adding an `-agentpath` VM parameter to a start script. The integration wizard has a check box for profiling 64-bit JREs, this changes the library path in the `-agentpath` VM parameter accordingly.

Comment: Anything I should know about using `jpenable` and then connecting to the computer remotely?

Comment: jpenable loads the correct libraries automatically. If jpenable runs with a 32-bit library, it can also connect to a 64-bit JVM and vice versa.